# Ставится ли запятая в предложение "Теперь он будет работать(,) как раньше"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, обороты-с-как

> Теперь он будет работать(,) как раньше

Ставится ли здесь запятая и почему?

Answer (score 2):

1. Для решения таких задач желателен **контекст**, тогда сделать выбор намного проще, например:

(1) *Теперь он будет работать  **как рАньше**,  как работал всю жизнь.*

Или (в сложном предложении): *Теперь он будет работать **как рАньше**, эта мысль радовала его.*

(2) *Теперь он не безработный! Теперь он  тоже будет рабОтать, **как рАньше**.*

Или (при перестановке): *Он будет рабОтать теперь, **как рАньше**.*

2. Мы видим, что оборот может быть необособленным обстоятельством и тесно примыкать к сказуемому (*работать как раньше*), а может быть сравнением: *работать, как (работал)  раньше*.

При обособлении ударение падает и на глагол, и на оборот. Если оборот не обособляется, ударение падает только на оборот.

3. Для обособления оборота предложение должно быть **достаточно распространенным**, то есть его содержание должно быть выраженным (в нем можно выделить тему и рему).  В противном случае оборот входит **в состав предложения** и не обособляется.
4. Если посмотреть статистику, то  ***как раньше*** в обособленном виде **встречается чаще.**

**Примеры:**

Будем жить **как раньше**. [Евгений Лукин.  (2013)]

Ты вернешься на работу и будешь рабОтать, **как раньше**. [А. А. Голицын. Ящик. История одного шоу // «Волга», 2009]

Будем вдвоем работать, **как раньше**.  [В. А. Обручев. В дебрях Центральной Азии (1951)]